# Не добавляется информация в ларавел 9. Ошибка - Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image' in 'field list'

Tags: php, sql, laravel

web.php:

```
Route::get('/admin/add-product', [PageController::class, 'addpage'])->name('addpage');
Route::post('/add-product', [PostController::class, 'addproduct'])->name('addproduct');
```

PostController:

```
 function addproduct(Request $request){
      $this->validate($request,[
         'photo'=>'image|mimes:jpeg,png,gif|max:2048'  ,   
         'title'=>'required|max:80',
      ]);
      $image_product = $request->file('photo');
      $new_image = rand()."_".$image_product->getClientOriginalName();
      $image_product->move(public_path('project/images'),$new_image);
      $post = new Products();
      $post->image = $new_image;
      $post->title = $request['title'];
      if($request->user()->post()->save($post)){
         $message = 'Success!';
      }
      return redirect()->back()->with([
         'message'=>$message
     ]);
   }
```

table:

```
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('photo');
            $table->string('name', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

view:

```
<form action="{{route('addproduct')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" name="title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Product_img</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" class="form-control" placeholder="photo"  name="photo">
            </div>
          
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                    Post Add
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

В БД тоже "photo" а не "image". Помогите пожалуйста могу скинуть PageController если нужно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У вас в БД созданы поля `photo` и `name`, а вы пытаетесь записать информацию в `image` и `title`.

Comment: Спасибо Антон, буду знать,  помогли очень.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function addproduct(Request $request){
  $this->validate($request,[
     'photo'=>'image|mimes:jpeg,png,gif|max:2048'  ,   
     'title'=>'required|max:80',
  ]);
  $image_product = $request->file('photo');
  $new_image = rand()."_".$image_product->getClientOriginalName();
  $image_product->move(public_path('project/images'),$new_image);
  $post = new Products();
  $post->image = $new_image; //Там Ваш ошибка не $post->image а $post->photo
  $post->title = $request['title'];
  if($request->user()->post()->save($post)){
     $message = 'Success!';
  }
  return redirect()->back()->with([
     'message'=>$message
 ]);
```

}

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Давно мучался с этой ошибкой.